# Input with variable length Classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, supervised-learning, time-varying-covariate

I have a dataset with patient information with discrete labels (labels are stages of a particular disease) which needs to be predicted (Basically a classification problem).

The data set looks something like below:

**Patient#|Visit#|Other medical features related to patient and visit|label (disease stage)**

So, I am interested in using patient's past visit data inorder to predict the current disease stage. But, the problem is that all the patients don't have equal number of visits. So, I can't just append the past visit information to predict the future visit label like below:

concat(Patient #n 1st visit (X = all input features)|label of this visit| Patient #n 2nd visit (X = all input features)) and then try to predict the label for 2nd visit using previous visit information.

In the above problem, the number of visit =1, but I have a varying number of visit for each patient. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you asking for a statistical solution to the scientific question or a programming solution to the restructuring of your data? If the former I think you may need to tell us what the scientific question is as the answer may be different. If the latter you might be better on another site.

Comment: On a high level, I am looking for a programming solution, particularly looking for the architecture/modification to an architecture which supports the above inputs.

Comment: One statistical way is to apply dimensional reduction and make the input length equal. But, I don't want to lose any information. So, looking for some other strategies.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is called time series classification. There are a few Python toolboxes that provide functionality for that, e.g. sktime https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime (I'm one of the developers). Many algorithms support unequal-length data in principle, but most implementations I am aware of only support equal-length data.

Comment: That's awesome. Many solutions pad zeros at the end/truncate the longer sequences? Does your method do any of these or can take in variable inputs and use them properly?